# Setting Facing Pages Margins In InDesign

Tags: javascript, com, adobe-indesign

I'm creating a new document with facing pages, and I want to set a margin that has a bigger margin on the spine side than the outer edge. In the UI, this is simple as there's an "Inside" and "Outside" margin edge. When scripting however, there's only a left/right though which is consistent left and right regardless of spine side.

How do I set outside / inside margins via a script as the `Document.MarginPreferences` have only top/bottom/left/right?

Comment: Are you sure, the right is consistent right and the left consistent left? I seem to remember that the right one is referring to the outer margin (which is indeed not covered in the documentation / API, but I figured it out after some experimenting)

Comment: That's very true. User error shall we say! The docs are relatively poor compared to the age of the api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left and right and relative to the spine. So consider left as the inside and right as the outside margin.

Comment: How do you mean relative to the spine? The outer margin on the left hand page is still on the left side, also relative to the spine. So the naming of the properties does not make much sense, I think? Edit: Oh, you mean when the book is closed?

Comment: Consider that left and right realluy worth for the first right page (or single possibly). Any other pages are either using thos value (odd/right) and mirrored values on even/left pages.

Comment: Well, I still think ```inner``` and ```outer``` would be a better and more intuitive way to name them…